# Vim's "ga" and utf-8 characters: What is <M-x>?

Tags: unicode, encoding, ascii

I pasted text `A ∩ B` into Vim in order to figure out how the "cap" character is represented.

Using its code, I would then figure out the right commands to print it out from a data analysis environment (specifically, Matlab, though that's not relevant to the question at this point).

The Bash command `file ~/tmp/tmp.txt` (where the text was pasted) shows that the encoding is UTF-8. So I did some web searching about UTF-8, Unicode, and ASCII.

In Vim, `:help :ga` says that it prints out the ASCII code.  For the "cap" character, it prints `<∩> 8745, Hex 2229, Oct 21051, Digr (U`. The Hex code is two bytes. From web searching, I'm finding that UTF-8 uses a variable number of bytes, with the first 127 ASCII characters taking up one byte. Since the most significant of 8 bits is for 128+, I assume that 128+ ASCII values take more than one byte because the most significant bit is used as a flag that one more byte is needed for the UTF-8 encoding.

The help for `:ga` says nothing about Unicode or UTF-8.  It says that when a character is larger than 127, the `<M-x>` form is also printed.  Pressing `Ctrl+]` on `<M-x>` doesn't warp me to an explanation of what it is.  I can't seem to find anything on the internet.

Can someone please point me to an explanation?

P.S. I am not exploring `:g8`, but I am curious about `<M-x>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<M-x>` is the notation for <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> on a PC or <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> on a Mac.

I understand that you would like to enter the ∩ ("cap") character easily, ideally using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>. I doubt that it is possible.

But maybe a good alternative is the digraph.

The `ga` commands tells you that you can input it in insert mode it using the sequence:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>

Another solution is to use the Unicode code:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `u2229`

If you want to know the utf8 code of the character you can use the `g8` command (that will return for the "cap" character `e2 88 a9`).

Remark: There is a simple logic that deduce the utf8 code from the Unicode value.

Comment: Thanks, Vivian.  I found this excursion into Unicode to be very educational.  I didn't have to use it, though, nor did I have to use a digraph. I initially anticipated having to specify a code to get the cap character, but as it turns out, I can just paste the string into Matlab string literal and the cap character is preserved. Just a funny observation, I made a typo in saying that "I am not exploring `g8`".  What I meant to say was that I am ***now*** exploring g8.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ;-) I'm glad we could help you.